# Store time values in Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, chat

Is there a way to store time values in Firebase using `Objective C`?

I am designing a chat app using Firebase and was wondering if I could add a time feature in it for each message being sent.

**Edited:**
What I have tried is:

```
[[self.firebase childByAutoId] setValue:@{@"date" : [NSDate date]}];
```

and an error pops up saying that it cannot store the NSDate value.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried , and whats wrong with it ?

Comment: you could do that easily in Parse .. OH NO, WAIT!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is!

```
[ref setValue@"2pm"]
```

or

```
[ref setValue@"20160216130100"]
```

or

```
any number of other ways to represent dates. Timestamps are spiffy.
```

Keep in mind that while they are strings, they still represent specific times and dates. You can sort by them as well as query for them.

If you are developing on MacOS/iOS, they work well with NSDate, NSDateFormatter, NSDateComponents.

A date string:

```
NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMdddd HH:mm:ss"];  //20160217 13:14:22
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: myDate];

[ref setValue:dateString]
```

You should carefully consider how you want your date formatted for consistency throughout your app and data.

I would suggest investigating the Firebase timestamp function.

Comment: I have tried that out. But do I have to first convert the NSDate value to a string?